# Event Handling in React js

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(true)
    const showDiv = () => {
        if (show) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("skills-hero")[0].style.display = "flex"

        }
        else if (!show) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("skills-hero")[0].style.display = "none"
        }
    }
```

This is simple logic but it is not working and not giving any error too.
I just don't under stand why it doesn't working

Comment: Are these `skills-hero` elements part of your react component tree? If so, you shouldn't be manipulating their style directly. If they're not part of the component tree then it may be necessary, but how are you calling showDiv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities why your code is not working:

1. The `skill-hero` element is defined inside the 'root' element (where you are attaching your Reactjs app. *assuming you are attaching your react app to the real DOM*. Hence the element is getting overridden by the react app.
2. function `showDiv` is not returning anything, I presume react will complain if you call the function inside the `return`(jsx) function.

To make your example work:

Inside Index.html

```html
  <div class="skills-hero">
    <div class="p">1</div>
    <div class="p">2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="root"></div>
```

Inside Javascript

```js
const MyFunc = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(true);
  const showDiv = () => {
    if (show) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("skills-hero")[0].style.display = "flex";
    } else if (!show) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("skills-hero")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
    return "some dummy text";
  };
  return showDiv();
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyFunc />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Note: This method frowned upon.  ^^^

You should avoid direct DOM manipulation in ReactJs mainly because:

- performance
- security (XSS)
- and `ReactDOM` does the dom-manipulation for you efficiently.
- it makes out lives way easier
- etc...

```
    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
    const showDiv = () => show ? <div className="skills-hero"> </div> : null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't select jsx elements with `getElementsByClassName` because they are not in the real dom. Your real DOM is empty in React.

You might want to do conditional rendering instead;

```
 show && <div className="skills-hero"></div>
```

something like this.